# Проблема с создание автозамены кода на странице

Tags: php, mysql, регулярные-выражения, str-replace

Суть кода в том, что при наличии определнного кода на странице например "view_plugin(1)", он должен замениться на данные полученные из базы misql. Но код работает только при вызове один раз, а не обрабатывает всю страницу и не заменятет на указанные айди. А если вызываю больше одного раза на странице то получаю массив которые не получается никак обработать. HELP. сори за баян если чтою

```
function view_plugin($search){
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `site_posts` WHERE `post_type`='plugins' && `id`='$search'";
    $query = get_value($sql);
    if(!empty($query)){
        $item = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
        if($item==null){return 'is null 2'.$search;}
        else{return htmlspecialchars_decode($item['content']);}
    }

    else{return 'error';}

}
function view_content(){
    $return = htmlspecialchars_decode(get_page()['content']);
    if(preg_match_all("/view_plugin[\(](?P<id>.+?)[\.)]/", ($return), $find)){
    $return = str_replace($find[0], view_plugin($find['id']), $return);
    return $return;
    }
    //return var_dump($find['id']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function view_content(){
  $return = htmlspecialchars_decode(get_page()['content']);
  if(preg_match_all("/view_plugin[\(](?P<id>.+?)[\.)]/", ($return), $find)){
    if(!empty($find[1])) {
      foreach($find[1] as $k=>$id){
        $return = str_replace($find[0][$k], view_plugin($id), $return);
      }
    }
    return $return;
  }
}
```

попробуйте так

Comment: в php нет модификатора `g`,  но вместо него для глобального поиска есть функция preg_match_all(), которая итак используется в примере из первого поста. Поэтому ваш ответ не является ответом, и более того, он ошибочный.

Comment: @Эдуард, да верно, спутал с другим языком. Поправил, спасибо.

Comment: @Эдуард, дааа чет немного пригорел) извиняюсь